# How to pass parameter to sitecore controller rendering method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sitecore

I have this on my cshtml page

```
<div class="liveMatch-timer">
            @Html.Sitecore().Controller("Blog", "LiveBlogHeader")
        </div>
```

And this is my controller

```
    public PartialViewResult LiveBlogHeader()
    {
        var matchHeader = GetMatchDayHeader();
        return PartialView(BlogConstant.LiveBlogHeaderPath, matchHeader);
    }
```

I have one hidden field with the name ***"liveMatchItemId"*** on my cshtml page. I would like to pass its value to controller so that I can access it inside controller. I am expecting to change controller definition something like this

```
public PartialViewResult LiveBlogHeader(string liveMatchItemId)
```

Anyone can help me understand on how can I do this? I am new to sitecore and MVC.

***EDIT***: I am able to achieve this using below code

```
@Html.Action("LiveBlogHeader", "Blog", new { liveMatchItemId = "12" })
```

But how can I set hidden field value instead of static field "12"?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could use something like:
    `@Html.Action("LiveBlogHeader", "Blog", new { liveMatchItemId = Model.LiveMatchItemId })`

Where Model.LiveMatchItemId is the property that you want to pass to the controller.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to declare model with hidden field's value? I am new to MVC

Comment: You need to have a class that will represent your model. Let's say public class ViewModel. Inside it, you need to add a property: public string LiveMatchItemId {get;set;}. Your controller will set that value: var model = new ViewModel(){ LiveMatchItemId = "YOUR VALUE" }; and return View("path", model); Inside your view: @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LiveMatchItemId)